# PHP database login script issue

Tags: php, html, authentication

My login page for future users is allowing any username and any password access. This code is in a file called Login.php and should direct you to Account.php But it is taking you there regardless of what you type in the forms.

```
<?php
require 'Connections/Connections.php';
include('header.php');
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['Login'])){

    $UN= $_POST['Username'];
    $PW = $_POST['Password'];

    $result = $con->query("Select * from users where Username='$UN' AND Password='$PW'");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];

    header('Location: Account.php');
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <link href="style/UserStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="LoginForm" id="LoginForm">

        <div class="FormElement">
            <input name="Username" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>

        <div class="FormElement">
            <input name="Password" type="Password" required="required" class="TField" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <div class="FormElement">
            <input name="Login" type="submit" class="button" id="Login" placeholder="Login">
        </div>
</body>
```

The connection.php that connects to my database and creates the variable $con

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "MyRealUsername", "MyRealPassword"); 
mysql_select_db("Registration"); 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "MyRealUsername", "MyRealPassword", "Registration");
?>
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Add checks - if such user found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make following changes in your php code . You are currently only checking for post variable and authenticating user. After fetching values from database please check result array and then redirect to Account.php if user exists in database else redirect to Login.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Login'])){

    $UN= $_POST['Username'];
    $PW = $_POST['Password'];

    $result = $con->query("Select * from users where Username='$UN' AND Password='$PW'");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if( isset($row) &&  $row['UserID'] != "" ){ // authenticated user, redirect to account page
    $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];

    header('Location: Account.php');

    }else{ // redirect to login page
        header('Location: Login.php');

    }
}
?>
```

Also Please sanitize input values in query string to prevent sql injection as below.

```
    $UN= $con->real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
    $PW = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);

$result = $con->query("Select * from users where Username='$UN' AND Password='$PW'");
```

Comment: Worked Great, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do not validate User/Password combination.

You get the user record from the database:

```
$UN= $_POST['Username'];
$PW = $_POST['Password'];

$result = $con->query("Select * from users where Username='$UN' AND Password='$PW'");

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

But then you DO NOT check whether such record exits and just log in the user regardlessly.

Add this check:

```
if ($row) {
   $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];

   header('Location: Account.php');
}
```

One more thing, these two lines in `connection.php` are totally useless since they use older PHP Mysql library:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "MyRealUsername", "MyRealPassword"); 
mysql_select_db("Registration");
```

One more important thing, **always filter the user input** before passing it into SQL query, since not filtering opens you application to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    /* Only execute code if it is a post request */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        /* Make sure all variables are at least set */
        if( isset( $_POST['Login'], $_POST['Username'], $_POST['Password'] ) ){

            /* basic filtering of posted data */
            $username=mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, filter_input( FILTER_POST, 'Username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
            $password=mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, filter_input( FILTER_POST, 'Password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );

            /* Only proceed if there are non empty values after filtering */
            if( !empty( $username ) && !empty( $password ) ){

                $sql="select * from `users` where `Username`='".$username."' and `password`='".$password."';";
                $result=$con->query( $sql );
                $uid=false;

                /* Check you have a result */
                if( $result && $result->num_rows() > 0 ){
                    while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ){
                        $uid=$rs->UserID;
                    }
                }
                if( $uid ) {
                    $_SESSION["UserID"]=$uid;
                    header( 'location: account.php' );  
                }

            }



            /*
              ------------------------------------------------
              Alternative method, using a "prepared statement"
              ------------------------------------------------

              You do not need to be so particular filtering data
              that is used in the sql query...

            */
            $sql_prepared='select `UserID` from `users` where `Username`=? and `Password`=?';

            $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql_prepared );
            $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $username, $password );

            $username=$_POST['Username'];
            $password=$_POST['Password'];

            /* Only process if we have non-empty values */
            if( !empty( $username ) && !empty( $password ) ){

                $result=$stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result( $uid );

                if( $result ){
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $stmt->close();

                    $_SESSION["UserID"]=$uid;
                    header( 'location: account.php' );  
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```